# Solr query syntax for searching term sequence including blank character for tokenized field

Tags: solr, lucene

I was wondering what is the correct query syntax for searching sequence of terms with blank character (space) in the middle of the sequence with using regex. Suppose I am looking for a query syntax with using fq parameter. For example suppose I want to search for all documents having "hello world" sequence using fq parameter. I am not sure why using `fq=content:/.*hello world.*/` did not work for tokenized field in this situation. However, `fq=content:/.*hello.*/` did work for the same field. Is there any possible fq query syntax for such searching requirement?

Comment: Regexes don't work here because lucene regexes must match a single term, not the entire field contents.  Since "hello" and "world" are tokenized into separate fields, they and both be matched with one regex.  A phrase query should work just fine though.  [My answer here covers a lot of the same ground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634032/lucene-search-for-terms-that-match-a-regex/32635828#32635828).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one Phrase queries.

```
/select?q=content:"hello world"
```

use quotes(") for hello wolrd

Comment: I was aware of "q" parameter, what about the fq one?

Comment: same thing can be done with "fq"  like,  `/select?q="shoes"&fq=category:"footwear"`